# Where should i get working URL of Teamprise plugin download for eclipse to access TFS server?

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, tfs, teamprise

I was working as an android developer. My development tools are Eclipse gelileo. i need help in accessing TFS server from my eclipse like svn . For that i googled and downloaded eclipse plugin .zip file of Teamprise plugin  and installed into eclipse. but unfortunately that plug in is not working properly. so i need a working URL of teamprise plugin to download from net directly into my eclipse gelileo. i got this link(http://update.teamprise.com/plugin/3/) by googling  but it is not working.

I am facing the following problem when trying to open  `Team Foundation Server Explorer` perspective in eclipse.

```
Could not create the view: Plug-in com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui was unable to load class com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.views.TeamExplorerView.
```

Can any one help me in this ?

Any help will be appreciated great.

Thanks,
Sathish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4240

How to use this plugin:

[Team Explorer Everywhere - A Plug-in to access TFS from Eclipse](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=519)

Comment: Hi NgM, Initially I tried with the links what you have suggested above, but still they are not working properly. so that i am searching for other alternatives. Could you please help me?

Comment: What doesn't work properly?  There isn't any alternative that am aware of.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is i am unable to open team foundation server explorer perspective. if i try to open this perspective i am getting the following error log. `Could not create the view: Plug-in com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui was unable to load class com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.views.TeamExplorerView.`,

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tee/thread/11cb8ab7-4f70-48f3-88be-101cf63a87f2/  was the only similar article I found.  I would post on MSDN if that suggestion doesn't help you

Comment: I have read and tried with new instance of eclipse . it is working fine. Thanks. Because of new with TFS and TeamPrise, where should i get complete tutorial that explains me that how to work with eclipse+TeamPrise+TFS? If possible can you suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

you need java version 1.7 or 1.8

as example you can install java using [SDKMAN](https://wimdeblauwe.wordpress.com/2018/09/26/switching-between-jdk-8-and-11-using-sdkman/)